# oledb connection error for stack trace

Tags: .net, ms-access, oledbexception

Hi All 
       I'm doing CRM Application in ASP.net. for which i use MS Access as back end. On Localhost no any oledb exception error occure while the same application upload on server then there will find oledb exception (occasionally not always,but when find oledb exception then continuously same error occure)

below I'm using code for connection string in web.config file

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SolDBConnectionstring" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\KRISP.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"
       providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

& other code use in Dataaccess.vb file for connection open

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public Class DataAccess

#Region "VARIABLE DECLARATIONS"
    Dim strErrorMsg As String = ""
    Public bSuccess As Boolean
    Dim objConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim objCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim objDTAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
#End Region

    Private Sub OpenConnection()
        Try
            Me.objConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("SolDBConnectionstring").ConnectionString)
            Me.objConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|KRISP.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
            If objConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                Me.objConnection.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Error is:

> Unspecified error
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error

Source Error:

Line 494:            'End If
Line 495:        Catch ex As Exception
Line 496:            Throw ex
Line 497:
Line 498:        Finally

Source File: d:\hosting\nitindia\App_Code\EmployeeManager.vb    Line: 496

Stack Trace:

> [OleDbException (0x80004005): Unspecified error]
>       EmployeeManager.isUser(String strUID, String strPswd) in d:\hosting\nitindia\App_Code\EmployeeManager.vb:496
>       Employees.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\hosting\nitindia\Employees.aspx.vb:37
>       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

So Please check above code & if you find any solution for above problem.please reply with your great logic.

Comment: Unspecified error
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error

Comment: Can you update the question with the Stack Trace?